# how to delete in a list from x to y?

Tags: python, list

i was wondering about how to delete multiple values from index x to y,
this is currently what im trying to:

```
first_num = None
second_num = None
while True:
   first_or_last = "first" if first_num is None else "last"
   text = str("Enter the {} index number to start deleting: ").format(first_or_last)
   remove_ftl_input = input(text)
   if first_num is None or second_num is None:
      if remove_ftl_input.isdigit():
         if first_num is None:
            first_num = int(remove_ftl_input)
      elif first_num is not None and second_num is None:
            second_num = int(remove_ftl_input)
      if first_num is not None and second_num is not None:
         for x in range(0, first_num-second_num):
            try:
               # note: every loop index shifts by -1 thats why first-num i assume?
               found_items_list.pop(first_num)
            except IndexError:
               print(str(x) + " was out of reach.")
```

Comment: You want to delete a number in index `x`and put it in index `y`?

Comment: You can delete elements from a list while iterating over it, as long as you work right to left. Deleting rightmost items does not change the indexes of the remaining items. `for x in reversed(range(0, first_num-second_num))` shoud work:

Answer (score 1):

> how to delete multiple values from index x

Why not just join the ranges that you want to keep

```
>>> list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> first = 3
>>> last = 4
>>> list = list[:first] + list[last+1:]
>>> list
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7]
```